# How to upgrade flash player on usb-live Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, flash, live-usb, partial-upgrade

A website requires an upgrade of flash player(while running firefox). My current configuration is:

- live-usb of 11.10 Ubuntu
- notebook with no internal hdd
- one external usb hdd
- Internet access

Can (and how) I permanently upgrade flash player on my live-usb Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you make the USB persistent

Comment: How can I find out if the live-usb is persistent? I used UNetbootin and if I can remember correctly I used default settings.

Answer (score 1):

You either need a persistent install or Full install.
Usb-creator and UNetbootin will make persistent installs.
A full install requires an 8GB drive, (you could put it on the USB HDD).

With either method you can then use Synaptic to upgrade your player.

You could also make persistent partitions on the external USB HDD.

Comment: So can I 1) create persistent install on external hdd without loosing any data and with partitioning it when I boot from live-usb? 2) create persistent install on usb stick (I have spare 4GB usb stick with me which I can format do whatever is needed) when booted from live-usb? Do I need to download Ubuntu iso again?

Comment: 1) use gparted to add an extended partition at the end of the drive. Add an ext4 partition for / and another ext4 for home, (optional). Add a third for swap.

Comment: Use manual partitioning and install to the above extended partitions. 2) Usb-creator, Universal and UNetbootin have persistence options. If you have the Live CD, run Startup Disk Creator.. You will be able to select up to 3GB Reserved extra space. You need more than 4GB for a full install

Comment: I thought that persistent install won't let me install stuff & do upgrades.